# How can I use .NET Core in C# interactive?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c#-interactive

How can I make the C# interactive console inside Visual Studio use .NET Core instead of .NET Framework?

By default when it starts it shows that it is using .NET Framework in parenthesis in the title bar.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2019 16.8.3 (and probably in earlier versions, but I don't know how much earlier) you can execute:

```
#reset core
```

This resets the C# interactive console and makes it use .NET Core.

Comment: How can you make this the default?

Comment: @JoelMueller you can switch back to .NET Framework with `#reset 32|64`

Comment: thanks for the answer. It seems like it only works if you run `csi` through VS. Not if you try it direct

Comment: @JoelMueller The dotnet/roslyn github shows a PR which makes .NET Core the default for Interactive. It's listed as part of Milestone 17.9 P1 (latest released version of VS 2022 is 17.8), so I guess it's coming soon. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/70127