# Is there a way to get access to the DateTime.UnixEpoch field from C# Interactive in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#-interactive

I'm trying to convert a timestamp to DateTime object in C# interactive using DateTime.UnixEpoch.

I have no problem doing it in my application code, but I can't get access to DateTime.UnixEpoch in C# Interactive.

I managed to convert a timestamp using suggestion from this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/21895909). It works in C# interactive just fine.

Now I'm curious why does DateTime.UnixEpoch accessable in my regular code and does not in my C# interactive envinroment.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.7.3 and my project targeting .NET 7.0

Here is my code in C# interactive:

```
> double timeStamp = 1693620016;
. DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UnixEpoch;
. dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timeStamp);
. Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Date);
```

Here is the Output:

```
(2,30): error CS0117: 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'UnixEpoch'
```

Comment: What version of .NET is your csproj targeting? The UnixEpoch member isn’t in .NET Framework 4.x.

Comment: @Dai I'm using .NET 7.0

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232414/how-can-i-use-net-core-in-c-sharp-interactive

Comment: @Dai You are right. Swithching to core by using "#reset core" command solved my problem. 
I've also noticed that there is a targeting framework in the header of the C# interactive window and one can choose between .Net Framework 32 or 64 or .Net Core. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# Interactive enter the following command:

```
#reset core
```

This command swithches target framework for C# interactive.

The current target framework can be found on the [title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myRzs.png) of the C# Interactive tab.

The answer from the [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232414/how-can-i-use-net-core-in-c-sharp-interactive) suggested by @Dai worked here.